# Add only one row of a particular column to a count/group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

Raw data:

| Category | Serial Number |
| --- | --- |
| Sports | 3462 |
| Sports | 4373 |
| Sports | 3453 |
| Auto | 7742 |
| Auto | 1247 |
| Auto | 3463 |
| Auto | 1242 |
| Auto | 7746 |

My goal with select query is to get that data looking like this:

| Category | Serial Number Count | Example Serial Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sports | 3 | 3462 |
| Auto | 4 | 7742 |

My current query:

```
SELECT
   Category,
   COUNT( [Serial Number] ) AS [Serial Number Count]
FROM
    abcDB
GROUP BY
    Category
```

The above query has everything aside from that last column where I just need ONE of the serial numbers from each category as an example. It doesn't matter which serial number it is as long as it falls into the correct category.

Can someone please edit my query so it includes a column like this? Thank you.

Comment: `MAX`, `MIN` etc etc any aggregate function

Comment: A quick-fix is to use `MIN` or `MAX`, though those will give you edge-cases rather than "typical" values. SQL Server does have the ability to return random rows in a group, but you'd have to restructure your query.

Comment: Maybe this article describes what you're after? https://www.kodyaz.com/articles/top-n-random-rows-foreach-category-or-group.aspx

Comment: @Dai - for this use case, OP doesn't need a typical value, just any of them. As such, even extreme values (i.e. min, max) are just as good as any.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

Window function `ROW_NUMBER()` is very handy for such scenario.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Category VARCHAR(20),Serial_Number VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @tbl (Category, Serial_Number) VALUES
('Sports', '3462'),
('Sports', '4373'),
('Sports', '3453'),
('Auto', '7742'),
('Auto', '1247'),
('Auto', '3463'),
('Auto', '1242'),
('Auto', '7746')
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY @@spid) AS seq
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY @@spid) AS cnt
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT Category, Serial_Number, cnt
FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1;
```

**Output**

| Category | Serial_Number | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Auto | 7742 | 5 |
| Sports | 3462 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

The following might work if you were to return a random row in a group

```
CREATE TABLE abcDB (
    Category VARCHAR(20),
    Serial_Number INT
);


INSERT INTO abcDB (Category, Serial_Number)
VALUES
    ('Sports', 3462),
    ('Sports', 4373),
    ('Sports', 3453),
    ('Auto', 7742),
    ('Auto', 1247),
    ('Auto', 3463),
    ('Auto', 1242),
    ('Auto', 7746);

WITH main_table AS (
  SELECT
    Category,
    Serial_Number AS Example_Serial_Number,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Category) AS Serial_Number_Count,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Serial_Number) AS ranking
  FROM abcDB
)

SELECT
  Category,
  Serial_Number_Count,
  Example_Serial_Number
FROM main_table
WHERE ranking = FLOOR(RAND()*(Serial_Number_Count-1+1)+1);
```

| Category | Serial_Number_Count | Example_Serial_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Auto | 5 | 1247 |
| Sports | 3 | 3462 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YKROOK22)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).